# Change state of individual div (that is inside a map) instead of changing the state of all div's inside the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that is checking if some state is true or false. I show a `<p>` tag if true and hide a `<h3>`. I am pulling the data from a gaphQL query so there is a map method and there are three `<Card>'s` **now if I click the card and run my `showFull` function it shows the p tags on all the elements, instead I just want to isolate the specific one it is clicking on**.

Here is my component

```
<Testimonials className="testimonaials">
        {data.allDatoCmsTestimonial.edges.map(({ node: testimonial }) => (
          <Card onClick={showFull} background={testimonial.testimonialImage.url}>      
            {testimonialFull ? 
              <p>{testimonial.fullLengthQuote}</p>
            :
              <h3>{testimonial.shortQuote}</h3>

            }        
          </Card>
        ))}
      </Testimonials>
```

Here is my state and my function

```
const [testimonialFull, setTestimonialFull] = useState(false)

  const showFull  = () => {
    setTestimonialFull(true)
  }
```

**Attempting Alexander's answer.** The issue I am having now is `Cannot read property 'testimonialImage' of undefined`

Here is the component

```
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {

  const TestimonialCard = ({testimonial})=>{
    const [showFull, setShowFull] = useState(false)
    const handleClick = useCallback(()=>{
       setShowFull(true)
       //setShowFull(s=>!s)//If you want toggle behaviour
    },[])
    return <Card onClick={handleClick} background={testimonial.testimonialImage.url}>      
     {showFull ? 
       <p>{testimonial.fullLengthQuote}</p>
      :
       <h3>{testimonial.shortQuote}</h3>
     }        
   </Card>
 }

  return (
  ...
```

Here is where I invoke it in the map function

```
 ...
    return ( 

    ... (bunch of other jsx/html)        

    <Testimonials className="testimonaials">
      {data.allDatoCmsTestimonial.edges.map(({ node: testimonial }) => (
        <TestimonialCard/>
      ))}
     </Testimonials>

     ...
```

Comment: Since you want to handle testimonial view for each `Card` component. It should be available for each Card component. And hence it should be in state `Card` component's state and not its parent. @alexander-vidaurre-arroyo is suggesting same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the cards in a custom component

```
const TestimonialCard = ({testimonial})=>{
   const [showFull, setShowFull] = useState(false)
   const handleClick = useCallback(()=>{
      setShowFull(true)
      //setShowFull(s=>!s)//If you want toggle behaviour
   },[])
   return <Card onClick={handleClick} background={testimonial.testimonialImage.url}>      
    {showFull ? 
      <p>{testimonial.fullLengthQuote}</p>
     :
      <h3>{testimonial.shortQuote}</h3>
    }        
  </Card>
}
```

Comment: I added my attempt at your question. I am stuck because now my graphQL variable is undefined.

Comment: First, put TestimonialCard outside any component, then  pass testimonial props `<TestimonialCard testimonial={testimonial}/>`

Comment: If I wanted the toggle function I tried this `setShowFull(!showFull)` but doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

Comment: It's because useCallback deps (second arg) is an empty array, therefore showFull inside handleClick scope always has initial value (false). Try passing [showFull] as second arg or better use a function for update state setShowFull(show=>!show)

Comment: Check this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates and this other https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback